# pathlocationstrategy angular 2 and laravel and .htaccess

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, laravel, http-status-code-404

I have trouble setting up the .htaccess for laravel and angular 2.
When I refresh the browser window I get a 404 page and try to avoid the html5 hashbang strategy.
I use routing from both Angular 2 and Laravel. The Laravel routing is used for retrieving templates (templateUrl in angular).
I started with https://github.com/sanex3339/laravel-5-angular-2-example

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out another way to solve it:

**App\Http\routes.php**

Prefix all your Angular routes with '/api'

```
// Angular 2 base route resolving
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'JSControllers\AngularRoutesController@index',
    'as' => 'home'
]);

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function()
{
  // Angular 2 base `/edit` route resolving
  Route::get('/edit', 'JSControllers\AngularRoutesController@index');

  // Angular 2 templates route
  Route::get('/templates/{template}', 'JSControllers\AngularTemplatesController@index');

  // API route
  Route::post('/api/upload-file', 'JSControllers\UploadController@uploadFile');

  // Angular 2 templates route
  Route::get('/blogdata', 'JSControllers\AngularDataController@blog');
});
```

**App\Exceptions\Handler.php**

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
    {
      return Response::view('backend.content');
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```